# Can I create Excel workbooks with only Pandas (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

In the pandas documentation, it says that the optional dependencies for Excel I/O are:

> xlrd/xlwt: Excel reading (xlrd) and writing (xlwt)
>
> openpyxl: openpyxl > version 2.4.0 for writing .xlsx files (xlrd >= 0.9.0)
>
> XlsxWriter: Alternative Excel writer

I can't install any external modules.  Is there any way to create an .xlsx file with just a pandas installation?

Edit: My question is - is there any built-in pandas functionality to create Excel workbooks, or is one of these optional dependencies required to create any Excel workbook at all?

I thought that openpyxl was part of a pandas install, but turns out I had XlsxWriter installed.

Comment: Well, pandas documentation says that it requires these libraries. Not sure why you'd expect to get different answer than the one in the official documentation

Comment: I'm asking if at least one of these optional dependencies are required for Excel I/O, or if there is built-in Excel I/O functionality, and these optional dependencies provide extra functionality on top of built-in features

Comment: You installed pandas. Why can't you install one more module? If pandas requires module X for some functionality there is not much you can do to get this functionality to work without said module.

Comment: Yeah, I gotcha.  The only approved installation on the server is pandas--apparently, anything else is a major bureaucratic ask.  Thanks for the confirmation, I was hoping there's something, but it looks like I'm back to the drawing board

Comment: The last sentence of your post makes it sound like you have xlsxwriter installed, in which case you _should_ be able to write xlsx files (it's appropriately named).  So I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah I realize that sounds confusing.  I'm making a prototype, but it will eventually be deployed to the server, where I can only install pandas and no other external packages (as far as I was told)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pandas codebase does not duplicate Excel reading or writing functionality provided by the external libraries you listed.

Unlike the csv format, which Python itself provides native support for, if you don't have any of those libraries installed, you cannot read or write Excel spreadsheets.